# jQuery - How to change background color according to item that has class "selected"

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, background, navigation

I have this menu with a list of options of colors. One of the colors is "blue" and has a class of "selected", and my background-color is "blue". I want to change the background color according to which color has the class of selected. I already know how to change the class, but now I want to know how to identify the class "selected" with the coordinating color.

Here's my code:

**jQuery**:

```
var coorColor;
$(".item").click(function() {
    $(".item").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $("body").css("background", coorColor);
});

// THIS IS THE PART I NEED HELP WITH

if($(".item.red.selected")) {
    coorColor = "red";
}

if($(".item.green.selected")) {
    coorColor = "green";
}

etc...
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="item blue selected">Blue</li>
    <li class="item red">Red</li>
    <li class="item green">Green</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* because the item "blue" is selected by default the body's bg-color is blue by default but will change according to jQuery */

body {
    background: blue;
}

.selected {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #565756;
}
```

Comment: what happen if you replace $("body").css("background", coorColor); with $("body").css("background-color", $(this).text());

Comment: Ehh, I see what you're doing there, but (I have a confession) the link items don't actually say the color, it has a background-color property of it's color. So it would be more like `ul li.blue{background:blue;display:block;height:10px;width:10px}`

Comment: what about this : $("body").css("background-color", $(this).css('background-color'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the class in the selected element:

```
$(".item").click(function() {
  $(".item").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");

  if ($(this).hasclass("blue")) {
    coorColor = "blue";
  } else if ($(this).hasclass("red") {
    coorColor = "red";
  }

  $("body").css("background", coorColor);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler approach would be to use `data-` attributes:

```
<ul>
    <li data-color="blue"  class="item blue selected">Blue</li>
    <li data-color="red"   class="item red">Red</li>
    <li data-color="green" class="item green">Green</li>
</ul>
```

Your code would then become:

```
var coorColor = $('.item.selected').data('color');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have only those classes for the item you could do this

```
$(".item").click(function() {
    $(".item").removeClass("selected");

    /* this will eliminate the unwanted classes leaving just the color class */
    var coorColor = $(this).attr('class').replace(new RegExp('item|anotherClass| ', 'g'), '');

    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $("body").css("background", coorColor);
});
```